python pandas assign does not take a column name with eiphen (-) in it
There is a pandas df frame which has 4 columns - serverName,ip-address,key,value. The key value pairs have various entries and hence the servername,ip-address are having no entries
The assign function is not accepting ip-address, while I try the same with serverName, it is okay.
Is eiphen (-) being not accepted as part of below some kind of pandas or python limitation? I wanted to make it generic column header which is coming from variables and hence the header is 'ip-address' and also reason do not want to use a new column entry. if this is limitation need to work on all headers which may come with eiphen(-)

>>> data3 = data2.assign(ip-address=data2['ip-address'].ffill().astype(str)).loc[data2['ip-address'].isna()]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    data3 = data2.assign(ip-address=data2['ip-address'].ffill().astype(str)).loc[data2['ip-address'].isna()]
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
>>> data3 = data2.assign(ipaddress=data2['ip-address'].ffill().astype(str)).loc[data2['ip-address'].isna()]


I expected that the names with eiphen will be accepted.

It's "hyphen" and no, they can't be part of a Python identifier. Python sees this as a minus sign. You wrote ip - address = data2, in words "ip minus address is assigned data2".

so, when I'm processing my headers, i need to check if they have an eiphen (-) and preferably convert them as underscore so that i don't get into these errors. Thanks @Friedrich
